# Bokeh iterator callbacks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I just found this interesting example of using easily Bokeh widgets in a notebook.

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/3.0.3/examples/output/jupyter/push_notebook/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb

It works just fine. However, I do not understand how to get the actual values of the three sliders (w, A, Phi) after the plot is modified. I suppose I have to use callbacks but I do not know how. Can someone suggest some code? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. Do you want to see the values as a Label in the plot or do you want the values saved in an variabel? Right now you can see the selected values on the right of the sliders.

Comment: I would like to have the actual values saved in the variables. It should be accessible with the kwags properties but I am not sure How to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the values `w`, `A`, `f` and `phi` in a `ColumnDataSource` and get acces by `r.data_source.data['w'][0]`.

I do have to mention that I don't like the solution, because it seems unneccessary complicated.

### Example Code

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()

n = 2000

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x':x,
    'y':y,
    'w':[1]*n,
    'A':[1]*n,
    'phi':[0]*n,
    'f':['sin']*n
})


p = figure(title="simple line example", height=300, width=600, y_range=(-5,5),
           background_fill_color='#efefef')
r = p.line(x='x', y='y', color="#8888cc", line_width=1.5, alpha=0.8, source=source)

def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    
    num = len(r.data_source.data['y']) 

    r.data_source.data['f'] = [f]*n
    r.data_source.data['A'] = [A]*n
    r.data_source.data['w'] = [w]*n
    r.data_source.data['phi'] = [phi]*n
    
    r.data_source.data['y'] = A * func(w * x + phi)
    push_notebook()
    
show(p, notebook_handle=True)
interact(update, f=["sin", "cos"], w=(0,50), A=(1,10), phi=(0, 20, 0.1))
```

As you can see I store the data in the DataSource and create always a list with 2000 elements. This is really not needed, but the bokeh object ColumnDataSource is hijacking here and this only allows lists of equal length.

I also tried do define global variables, but they were not updates, so this is the only solution which is working so far.

Hope this helps you.